# Как отсортировать один массив объектов по расположению элементов в другом массиве в Python?

Tags: python, list, сортировка

Всем привет, такая ситуация Есть массив объектов для условности aaa. Есть массив идентификаторов возможных объектов bbb.В массиве aaa могут быть объекты,идентификаторов которых нету в bbb, и наоборот, в bbb могут быть ids, объектов с которыми нету в aaa. Каким образом я могу взять объекты из aaa, которые есть в bbb, еще и расположить в том же порядке, как они быи бы в bbb + применить доп фильтры по которым брать или не брать объект из aaa
то есть пример

```
aaa = [{"id":1; "name": "abc"}, {"id":2; "name": "ggg"}. {"id":3; "name": "yyy"}, {"id":4; "name": "xxx"];
```

второй массив

```
bbb = [33,4,55,11,8,1];
```

результат:

```
[{"id":4; "name": "xxx"}, {"id":1; "name": "abc"}]
```

Comment: Не заводите новый вопрос, а редактируйте старый

Answer (score 1):

как вариант можно сделать через промежуточный словарь

```
temp = {x['id']: x for x in aaa}

res =[]
for x in bbb:
    y = temp.get(x)
    if y is not None:
        res.append(y)

print(res)
```

Comment: `res = [ temp.get(y) for y in bbb if y in temp ]`

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью модуля pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.DataFrame(index = bbb).join(pd.DataFrame(aaa)
                                     .set_index("id"), how="inner").reset_index().to_dict("records")
```

res:

```
[{'index': 4, 'name': 'xxx'}, {'index': 1, 'name': 'abc'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
lst = []
for a in aaa:
    if a['id'] in bbb: 
       # вот здесь вы можете доролнительно написать свои if-ы, обработать элементы и т.д.
       lst.append(a)
lst.sort(key=lambda x: bbb.index(x['id']))
print(lst)
```

Можно записать это в одну строку:

```
lst = sorted(filter(lambda x: x['id'] in bbb, aaa), key=lambda x: bbb.index(x['id']))
```

где вместо `lambda x: x['id'] in bbb` вы можете записывать вашу собственную функцию фильтрации. например так:

```
def f(x):
    if x['id'] not in bbb:
        return False
    if x['id'] > 5: # допустим, вам нужны id < 5
        return False
    return True

lst = sorted(filter(f, aaa), key=lambda x: bbb.index(x['id']))
```